# All solutions of $z\in \Bbb C, \cos z = i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to find all solutions to $\cos z = i$

Okay so $$\cos z = \frac12(e^{-iz}+e^{iz})=i$$
$$e^{-iz}+e^{iz}=2i$$
$$e^{-iz}+e^{iz}=2e^{\frac\pi 2i + 2\pi i n},n\in \Bbb Z$$
$$1+e^{2iz} = 2e^{z\frac\pi 2 i + 2z\pi n i}$$

Now I am lost. I can't seem to factor out a single $z$ so I can't get it, thanks for ideas!

Comment: Let $e^{iz}=p$, then $p+1/p=2i$. Solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $e^{iz}=ip\ (*)$,

$$ip+\frac1{ip}=2i,$$or
$$p^2-2p-1=0,$$

$$p=1\pm\sqrt{2}.$$

Then
$$iz=\ln(\sqrt2+1)+i\frac\pi2+i2k\pi\lor iz=\ln(\sqrt2-1)-i\frac\pi2-i2k\pi\ (**),$$
i.e.
$$z=\frac{2k+1}2\pi+i\ln(\sqrt2-1)\lor z=-\frac{2k+1}2\pi-i\ln(\sqrt2-1).$$

---

(*) This substitution came after noticing that the solution is pure imaginary.

(**) The sign of $k$ was chosen to let symmetry appear: indeed, $\cos(z)$ being an even function, $z$ and $-z$ are both solutions. We also used $\ln(\sqrt2-1)=-\ln(\sqrt2+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e^{iz} = p$ then we have: $$p+\frac1p=2i$$
$$\iff p^2+1=2ip$$
$$\iff p^2-2ip+1=0$$
$$\iff p=\frac{2i\pm \sqrt{-4-4}}{2}$$
$$\iff p=i+\frac{\sqrt{8}i}{2}=i+\sqrt{2}i$$
$$\iff e^{zi}=i+\sqrt{2}$$
$$\iff iz=\ln(i+\sqrt{2}i)$$
$$\iff z=-i \ln(i+\sqrt{2}i)+2\pi ni,n\in\Bbb Z$$
$$\text{ since } \ln(i+\sqrt{2}i)=\ln|i+\sqrt{2}i| + i\arg(i+\sqrt2 i)$$
We get the final result(remembering our $\pm$!)$$z=-i \ln(\sqrt{2}\pm1) -\frac\pi2+2\pi n i$$

Comment: Double check your result, there are two errors left.